# Как отключить экспоненциальное отображение чисел в soapui для больших значений?

Tags: json, postman, soapui

Во время тестирования сервисов приложения на spring-boot использую soapui
возникла проблема с тем, что поля, содержащие числа с плавающей запятой, округляются в неудобный для тестирования вид

```
"beta": 6.08472032597752E7
```

То есть степень 10 заменяется на компьютерное представление, в то время как при работе с постаманом такой проблемы нет, числа отображаются нормально

```
"beta": 60847203.2597752
```

Как отключить этот фукционал по преобразованию в постмане

`версия soapui`  SoapUI 5.5.0

Если обратиться к вкладке RAW вместо JSON, то там отображение корректное

Answer (score 0):

Это нельзя выключить простым путём, а почему такой вид неудобен для тестирования? Опишите кейс в котором это мешает?
Данные преобразуются только на UI приложения
[image: Assert сверяющий float с преобразованным значением]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос